# Is it possible to pass a function from html into a lit-element?

Tags: javascript, polymer, lit-element

I have seen examples of passing a function from a parent lit-element to a child one like here - https://medium.com/@westbrook/litelement-to-do-app-1e08a31707a4

But I want the users of my element, not to be forced to create a wrapper element to use my element.

For example, my element is a dialog that computes some value.

I was hoping I could do something like this (html using my element):

```
<script>
 function latLongResult(lat,long)
    {
        console.log("resulting lat long called");
    }

</script>
    <lat-long-chooser id="latLongDialog" resultingLatLong=${latLongResult(lat,long)}></lat-long-chooser>
```

And then in my element:

```
export class LatLongChooser extends LitElement {


static get properties() {
    return {
      latDecimalDegrees: Number,
      longDecimalDegrees: Number,
      resultingLatLong: {
        type: Function,
      }
    };
  }

saveConvertedValues() {
       console.log("save other values called");
       this.resultingLatLong(this.latDecimalDegrees,this.longDecimalDegrees)
      }
```

When I try this, I get JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your element's code is fine, the way you're trying to set the function is what's a bit off.

You see, the syntax you're using would work if you were in a lit-html/lit-element render function (just with a few corrections, it would be `.resultingLatLong=${latLongResult}`)

However, since you're in a script at the main level you should do something like this:

```
<script>
 function latLongResult(lat,long){
    console.log("resulting lat long called");
 }
 // do it like this so that it's set as a property, setting it as an attribute would require some rather complicated extra code
 document.querySelector('#latLongDialog').resultingLatLong = latLongResult;

</script>
<lat-long-chooser id="latLongDialog"></lat-long-chooser>
```

Here's a [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lit-element-external-function-demo) with a minimal example of something similar in action

Comment: Thanks, I found that I could also bubble an event up and handle it in the parent, is that the  preferred way to do it, or is this preferred?

Comment: Well, this is a rather react-ish way of doing things, the general consensus seems to be that just bubbling an event is better, because for example, if in a new version you change what resultingLatLong receives when it's called it might break down a lot of things, with an event it's a bit easier to avoid those kind of maintenance hell issues and it also helps for reusability between projects

Answer (score 2):

You can also configure a observed attributes, in your property `resultingLatLong` in your `lat-long-chooser` and set the `attribute: false`  like that:

```
static get properties() {
    return {
      latDecimalDegrees: Number,
      longDecimalDegrees: Number,
      resultingLatLong: {
        type: Function,
        attribute: false
      }
    };
  }
```

This will prevent an observed attribute from being created for a property.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've access to the `window` object inside your components another way  to do this would be to pass the *name* of the function and access the function itself via `window[functionName]`:

```js
customElements.define('my-example', class extends LitElement {
  static properties = {
    greet: {}
  }

  _greet() {
    window[this.greet]('Hello World!');
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <button @click=${this._greet}>Greet</button>
    `;
  }
});
```

Then in your page:

```html
<body>
  <my-example greet="greetHandler"></my-example>
  <script>
    function greetHandler(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```